# Transformerless inverter from 20*12V batteries

Tags: inverter, transformerless

Is it possible to convert 240VDC from 20*12V batteries to 180VAC-240VAC pure Sine Wave?
i have an idea using H-Bridge mosfet drivers....But i have seen on web that 350Vdc is must to convert it to 240VDC...

Comment: Are you aware that a typical "12V" battery actually doesn't provide 12 volts?

Comment: As Olin says below - RMS is .707 of the peak voltage (look up RMS on Wikipedia) so for 240v RMS you need peaks of ~340v.

Comment: Thanks AL Kepp and John U for helping. i will figure out something else. But any way Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but awkward.  180 VAC RMS will have peaks of 254 V.  It would be much simpler if your DC was at least that.  If it were, you could use direct drive via PWM with some filtering.

Since 240 V isn't enough for the full excursion of even your minimum output, a more expensive, costly, and less efficient method will need to be used.  There are various topologies for that, but without knowing constraints and tradeoffs of your particular case it is pointless to recommend something.  One method boosts the DC to what is needed for the peaks, then uses direct drive from there.  Another does the high frequency chopping into a transformer like a switching power supply, but the regulation level is the much slower 50 or 60 Hz desired output.  Yet another way is to direct drive to whatever sine you can manage, then run that thru a transformer at the output frequency to get what you want.

Comment: So. I can use my Sine Wave and convert it to AC then use an transformer to step up to 220VAC. One more thing, how did u calculate the peak voltage?

Comment: @Auston: The peak voltage of a sine wave will be sqrt(2) higher than its RMS value.  180 * sqrt(2) = 255.

Comment: What if i use a transformer to step up that 170VAC RMS which i will be able to get with the H-bridge and sine wave to 230VAC?

Comment: @Auston: That leaves no room for the pass elemets, voltage regulation, or input voltage variation.  Pick something you can reliably make and regulate under all conditions, then set the tranformer ratio to get what you want from that.